# How to set another period to running JobService?

Tags: android, performance, android-service, android-service-binding

I start new JobService as:

```
 JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    if (jobScheduler != null) {
        jobScheduler.schedule(
                new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID_LOAD_IMAGE,
                        new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), ImageLoadJobService.class))
                        .setOverrideDeadline(0L)
                        .setPeriodic(900000)
                        .setPersisted(true)
                        .build()
        );
    }
```

And than user can change period of updating data. How can I change period of my JobService? Should I stop it and than repeat again?

**Thanks everyone for answers in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

You should call `jobScheduler.cancel(JOB_ID_LOAD_IMAGE);` and then reissue your job with the updated period as a new job via your code above.

Unfortunately, the API does not offer an update to the JobInfo object so cancelling then re-creating is the only way to issue a new period for your job.

Good Luck and Happy Coding!